# Expanded Preview Closes on Mobile Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll

I'm using this tutorial to create an expanding preview within a grid of thumbnails. On mobile the expanded div closes when you scroll up or down, and I can't seem to find what's causing it.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

New to javascript, so maybe I'm not looking for the right things. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `js/grid.js` file and delete the following code:

```
setup: function() {
    $( this ).on( "resize", $special.handler );
},
teardown: function() {
    $( this ).off( "resize", $special.handler );
},
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, I even tried taking out the whole $special event handler, but it still closes the div when I scroll

Comment: Then you are most likely not linking the file properly in your HTML. I removed that piece of code and it worked for me. If you delete the entire $special event handler, nothing will work anymore. Please post your code.

Comment: Actually, those lines of code were in another js file that was linked, it works perfectly thank you!